# E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1010) Error al intentar abrir un SplashActivity con un video

Tags: java, android-studio

Aqui mi codigo:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set portrait orientation
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        // Hide title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        try {
            VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
            setContentView(videoHolder);
            Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.x);
            videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);

            videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    jump();
                }
            });
            videoHolder.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            jump();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        jump();
        return true;
    }

    private void jump() {
        if (isFinishing())
            return;
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Al momento que ejecuto la aplicacion la pantalla me arroja un error que dice

> "No se puede reproducir el video"

Sin embargo me carga mi siguiente actividad sin problema luego del mensaje de error, hice el `SplashActivity` con un *.Gif* y lo hizo sin problema, la cosa es que quiero que las animaciones al inicio tengan sonido, por eso intento implementar un video con el mismo contenido del *.Gif*

Comment: Creo que es importante comentar que formato tienen tu video. Verificaste que en verdad sea el archivo x.* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cuanto al error que mencionas:

> "No se puede reproducir el video"

Principalmente estas son las causas por las cuales no se puede reproducir el audio:

- El archivo que se encuentra en el folder `/raw` puede que en realidad no  sea un archivo de video/audio, verifica que sea el archivo x.*.
- El archivo no fue generado con los [**codecs soportados por android**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats)

> Sin embargo me carga mi siguiente actividad sin problema

Carga la siguiente actividad ya que al ocurrir un error también llamas al método  `jump()` el cual realiza el `intent` para abrir la Activity.

```
 try {
      ...
      ...
       //Reproduce video.
      ...
      ...
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     jump();
   }
```

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.